# Return multipe <li> elements from React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return multiple `<li>` tags from my component's `render()` method, however React enforces you to have a single parent, which could be `</>`.
I'm performing some logic with element's parent, so I cannot have a parent for these `<li>` elements; `<ul>` for `<li>` elements is in another component and it cannot be moved. 
So how can I return multiple `<li>` elements from my component? Thanks.

Comment: Try React Fragment

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html   take a look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an array of elements too in React.

```
return ([<div />,<div />,<div/>])
```

Answer (score 3):

React Fragment

```
return (
  <>
    <li/>
    <li/>
  </>
)
```

or

```
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <li />
        <li />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
```

For more details https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <li />
        <li />
    </React.Fragment>
)
```